# Extract file names between files with date in them

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is kind of convoluted but I'll explain as best as I can. I need to extract all of the file names between 2 files that have the same date in the file name and after the latest one. Here is my very sparse code so far to extract the first file:

```
@echo off
setlocal

pushd \\server1.com\developer\inetpub\Ftproot\XMLs
echo.
for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%a in ('dir /b /o-d ABC*.xml') do (
    for /f %%b in ('dir /b /o-d ABC*%%a*.xml') do (echo %%~b - %%~tb &&goto:out)
)
:out
popd
```

This just finds the latest ABC xml file in the directory. Now I need to find the 2nd latest and list all of the files between the 2nd latest ABC xmls and all of the files after the latest ABC xml file.

I can't really do a `dir` listing for this as even a small subset would be hundreds of files. Here is a very small subset of what I expect to return.

```
08/20/2015  05:50 PM             8,829 BC6009490001_ACCTV21_20150820_CHG_367_107431247A.xml
08/20/2015  05:50 PM            11,552 BC6009490001_BALMIS_20150820_CHG_367_107432647B.xml
08/20/2015  05:49 PM               679 ABC_20150820_107481745D.xml
08/20/2015  05:48 PM             7,647 ID1779750001_BALMIS_20150820_NAC_5_1074336956.xml
08/20/2015  05:48 PM             7,650 ID1779740001_BALMIS_20150820_NAC_5_107447244U.xml
08/20/2015  05:48 PM             7,604 ID1778730001_BALMIS_20150820_NAC_5_107434944I.xml
08/20/2015  05:48 PM             7,786 ID1808430001_BALMIS_20150820_NAC_2_1074206446.xml
08/20/2015  05:43 PM             8,911 SB1522960001_ACCTV21_20150820_EXT_3_107249691J.xml
08/20/2015  05:43 PM             6,141 SB1522960001_BALMIS_20150820_EXT_3_107400191K.xml
08/20/2015  05:43 PM               623 ABC_20150820_1074331234.xml
```

So, I can find the latest ABC*.xml file easily but I want to get the 5:43 one and everything above it. The search date has to be extracted from the file name because sometimes it differs from the date `dir` returns.

Comment: Please add a small example of the `dir` listing and the desired output in this case.

Comment: @WOxxOm I have updated my question. This should be really easy but I haven't coded in batch for awhile. Thanks for your help.

Comment: so in other words: all files newer than (including) the last-but-one `ABC_*`?

Comment: @Stephan Yep, that's the jist of it.

Answer (score 0):

So, at first I came up with this:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "found=0"
pushd \\server1\developer\inetpub\Ftproot\XMLs
echo.
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[]" %%a in (
  'dir /b /o:-d *.xml^|find /i /n /v "^"'
 ) do ( 
  set "f3=%%b"
  IF "!f3:~0,3!" EQU "ABC" set /a "found+=1"
  IF "!found!" EQU "2" (
        Echo %%b
        Echo %%a Files Total
        Goto :out
     ) ELSE ( 
        echo %%b
  )
 )
:out
popd
```

and it worked just fine but it was slow. I remembered hearing about an issue with dir in a for loop where it had to iterate the entire directory before it could begin and with 32,000 files, that takes awhile. So, I posted it up on the dostips forum and with the help of foxidrive, I came up with this:

```
@echo off
dir /b /o:-d "\\server1\developer\inetpub\Ftproot\XMLs\*.xml" >"%temp%\filterABC.tmp"
set "found="
set "files="
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%temp%\filterABC.tmp") do (
      set "f3=%%a"
      echo %%a
      set /a files+=1
      IF /i "!f3:~0,3!" EQU "ABC" IF defined found goto :out
      IF /i "!f3:~0,3!" EQU "ABC" set "found=1"
   )
)>"%temp%\filterABC2.tmp"
:out
echo located !files! files in total
notepad "%temp%\filterABC2.tmp"
del "%temp%\filterABC.tmp"
```

Now it's working perfectly.